# How to close a PrinterJob dialog in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I'm having the following issue:

Our Swing application has a timeout which returns the user back to the login frame.

If a user opens a print dialog and leaves it open, and then tries to hit the print button after the timeout, our applications fails and the user is presented with an error. (The application logic expects the user to make a print choice and then executes some logic afterwards).

Is it possible to somehow close the print dialog when the application times out, or add a custom timeout to the print dialog?

**EDIT:**
What i have tried so far (MCVE):

```
public class JavaPrintTest implements Printable {
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
        if (pageIndex != 0)
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 36));
        g2.setPaint(Color.black);
        g2.drawString("Java Source and Support!", 144, 144);
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Window[] allWindows = Window.getWindows();
                        for (Window w:allWindows) {
                            w.setVisible(false);
                            w.dispose();
                        }
                        for (Frame frame : Frame.getFrames() ) {
                            frame.setVisible(false);
                            frame.dispose();
                        }
                    }
                },
                5000
        );

        PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        pj.setPrintable(new JavaPrintTest());

        if (pj.printDialog()) {
            try {
                pj.print();
            } catch (PrinterException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I start a timer that after 5 seconds will try to close the print dialog where it tries to iterate over all windows and all frames, but the dialog dosn't close.

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman I assume you've never done printing in Swing, you don't have direct access to the printer dialog

Comment: You could try having a look at the results from `Frame.getFrames`, maybe that will give you access to the printer dialog window so you can close it. Alternatively place a check in your API to check to see if the application has timed out or not before processing the remaining print job

Comment: @MadProgrammer, you are right, I just assuming, thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find & close all active windows before returning to the log-in window:

```
private void logout() {
    Window[] allWindows = Window.getWindows();
    for (Window w:allWindows) {
        w.setVisible(false);
        w.dispose();
    }
    returnToLoginWindow();
}
```

**EDIT:**
Print dialog is a native system dialog window which is not affected by dispose().
On Windows, for example, Java returns `sun.awt.windows.WPrintDialog`.
For such native dialogs, the only way I found is as a workaround:

```
for (Window w: allWindows) {
    //System.out.println(w.getClass().getSimpleName()+": "+w);
    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The following API **does not** affect the native dialog (at least on Windows):

```
WindowEvent windowClosing = new WindowEvent(w, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(windowClosing);
w.dispatchEvent(windowClosing);
w.setVisible(false);
w.dispose();
```

Comment: @Emil Kaminski Don't use java.util.Timer. Use **javax.swing.Timer**.

Comment: Doesn't matter which timer i use, the code is executed, but the print dialog still stays open. Have you actually tested that this works or are you just assuming that it should work?

Comment: +1 for the workaround. This of course requires that the print dialog has focus at the moment the ESC-key press is simulated (window.requestFocus(); doesn't seem to work), but i will accept this answer. Thanks for your time :)